# No gold badge after 10000 views?

Tags: support, badges

[One of my questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/17795/shyam?tab=questions&sort=views) has reached 10000  views, but I haven't got a gold badge still. Is it because of a rounding, i.e., is the count in between 9500-10000?

Comment: I find it astonishing that nearly 10,000 people have viewed that question - but not a single person has upvoted it, and the only answer has just 2 upvotes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: LOL, it was surprising for me as well. It will be interesting to see where the traffic came from.

Comment: I'd never even noticed that "views" value before, but having just looked at my own questions, I can't see much correlation between number of views and number of votes. Perhaps you just get a lot of views from non-ELU users if it makes it into the "hot questions" list. Anyway, I see you've got an "Electorate" badge on Main - that should be worth much more to the community!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, the number you see in your profile is rounded up. You can hover over it to see the actual figure, or visit the question itself and check the stats on the right-hand side.

[image]

[image]

Also, note that barely any badges are awarded instantly, especially not gold ones. The scripts that award them run in various intervals, going up all the way to 24 hours. So even if you did qualify for the badge right now you might still have to wait for one more day.